# Nginx URL Rewrite - delete from adressbar /administration/ after login

Tags: nginx

How Can I delete from my adressbar after login to backend www.domain.com **/administration/** index.php?
So my url after login will be like :

www.domain.com/index.php

My config:

```
server {
    server_name domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php;
    server_name www.domain.com;



    location / {
        rewrite ^([^\.]*)$ /$1.php;
    }

    location = / {
        rewrite ^ /index.php;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an arbitrary cookie (say, 'logged_admin=1') then check for that cookie in the `location /` block, like this

```
location / {
  if ($http_cookie ~ 'logged_admin=1;?') {
    rewrite ^/([^\.]*)$ /administration/$1.php last;
  }

  rewrite ^([^\.]*)$ /$1.php;
}
```

I should say that you should improve the regex in the if block to handle some edge cases like accessing `/administration/xyz.php` while logged-in as admin and so on.

Comment: esra2 reputation esra2